# Relay coil resistance measurements?

Tags: electrical, relay

My relay 5 pin has 12v 10 amps input rating. And, I measured its coil voltage with multimeter giving about 650 ohms. Now, I connect the relay to car battery 45 ah. Surprisingly, the current through 86 and 85 is around 0.4 amps as against the regular 10amps. I'm confused why it should not give around 0.017 amps under 12v and 650 ohms!!!! Also, how to make current flow to 0.017 amps???

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by: "Surprisingly, the current through 86 and 85 is around 0.4 amps as against the regular 10amps. "  The current carrying capability of the contacts (the 10 amps) has nothing to do with the coil current.  Perhaps you are not measuring the current correctly when it's operating.  Can you explain? Can you supply a drawing of how you making these measurements?

Comment: 86 connected to positive of car battery and 85 to ground. The measured current is 0.4 amps through the relay coil. Why 10 amps don't flow through the coil which has about 650 coil ohms??

Comment: Where are you placing the ammeter?  Are the other terminals of the coil connected to anything?

Comment: I want 5 pins relay of 12 v which will activate the coil with maximum current of 0.02 amps or 20 mAmps or less. If possible, 0.005 amps is also very much accepted. Please suggest such suitable relays under 12v dc. Thanks.

Comment: Im placing the multimeter in series with the car battery.

Comment: *"Im placing the multimeter in series with the car battery"* So are you actually measuring the total current draw from the battery, rather than the current through the relay?

Comment: You need to supply a diagram of what you are doing. At the moment what you describe is probably not what you really want.